# Can I use custom CSS and js plugin to put JavaScript in to validate my forms

Tags: plugins, javascript, forms, validation

I would like to put some front-end JavaScript validation to my forms, but was wondering, if I can put the JavaScript for the field validations in the custom CSS and js plugin, or do I need a specific plugin to do this.

Comment: Why would you need any plugin?  Just use the core functionality to register and enqueue your script.  https://wpmudev.com/blog/adding-scripts-and-styles-wordpress-enqueueing/

Comment: what is the custom CSS/JS plugin? If you have a question about a 3rd party plugin you need to ask either their official support routes or other users of that plugin in their communities, 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic here and not in this stacks scope

Comment: JDM, I have unfortunately never been able to get anything to work by enqueueng for over a year now, so had to resort to plugins. May I ask, if it's better to use jQuery or JavaScript for client side validation.

Comment: @SpencerHalstead you can do whatever you like in the frontend